# Increment last digits of string in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, increment, python-re

I would like to increment hostnames starting with 01 in python 3. I have found some solutions but i am having a issue after 09. My code increments it to 010. How can i solve this issue?

my code

`re.sub('\d(?!\d)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), hostname01)`

Comment: You can use `\d+` instead, right now it only takes the last digit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it increments "hostname01" to "hostname2". It should be like hostname01, hostname02, ........, hostname09, hostname10, hostname11,...

Comment: So it will be hostname14 instead of hostname014 which has to become hostname15? Like this `(?:[1-8]\d*|09)$` https://regex101.com/r/TcAgaC/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could match either a digit 1-9 followed by optional digits 0-9 or match 09

```
(?:[1-9]\d*|09)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m9pm0F/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/a3NmgH)

```
import re

hostnames = [
    "hostname01", "hostname08", "hostname09", "hostname10", "hostname99", "hostname675"
    ]
    
for hostname in hostnames:
    print(re.sub('(?:[1-9]\d*|09)$', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1), hostname))
```

Output

```
hostname02
hostname09
hostname10
hostname11
hostname100
hostname676
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for. I really appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: one more question. is it possible to start from hostname00 and increment? I tried with the same code but it did not work.

Comment: You could make the 9 optional `(?:[1-9]\d*|09?)$` https://regex101.com/r/5LLe9J/1 See https://ideone.com/1Vojbs

Answer (score 0):

Use zfill to add a 0

Like this:

```
import re
hostname01 = "hostname10"
print(re.sub('(\d+)', lambda x: str(int(x.group(0)) + 1).zfill(2), hostname01))
```